# UIView slide transitions, help needed & near-working code

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, subview, animatewithduration

I'm looking to do the following fully programmatically and have some code that ALMOST does it!

**Goal**

1. Transition between two master views, **viewOne** and **viewTwo**. 'viewOne' is the initial full-screen view.
2. Transition with a slide of differing direction and type

   a. using either left/right or up/down specifically

   b. be able to select direction (e.g. 'up' or 'down')

**Observed Code Response**

1. **[Good]** The code below successfully transitions between views
2. **[Problem]** The code below only ever uses the same transition, every time Left->Right!

**Core Code**

*(remaining code segments posted below in a second block)*

```
    func pick_view(showFirst: Bool) {

        let addedView   = (showFirst) ? viewOne : viewTwo;
        let removedView = (showFirst) ? viewTwo : viewOne;

        print("picking a new view");

        //let animationType = (showFirst) ? UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft : .TransitionFlipFromRight; //flip L->R or R-> depending

        addedView.alpha = 0;

        self.view.addSubview(addedView);

        print("old view off!");


        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.5, options: .TransitionCurlUp, animations: {  //.CurveLinear is an option too

            print("new view added");

            addedView.alpha = 1.0;

            addedView.frame = self.view.frame;

            }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in

                print("old view removed");

                removedView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width, 0, 0, 0);

                removedView.removeFromSuperview();
        });

        UIView.commitAnimations();

        return;
    }
```

**Remaining Code Segments**

*Recall that this is 100% programmatic. As such I feel this code here is exceptionally high value to be able to respond :)*

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var viewOne : UIView!;
    var viewTwo : UIView!;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();

        gen_views();
        pick_view(true);

        return;
    }

    func gen_views() {

        viewOne = UIView();
        viewOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
        viewOne.frame = self.view.frame;

        addSecondUIView(viewOne, dispStr: "4:30 PM");
        addSubviewButton(viewOne, return_msg: "Launch View #2", action_fcn:  "press_launch:");

        viewTwo = UIView();
        viewTwo.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();
        viewTwo.frame = self.view.frame;

        addSecondUIView(viewTwo, dispStr: "8:00 PM");
        addSubviewButton(viewTwo, return_msg: "Return from View #2", action_fcn:  "press_return:");

        viewTwo.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width, 0, 0, 0);       //init off-screen

        self.view.addSubview(viewOne);                                    //add em both!
        self.view.addSubview(viewTwo);

        return;
    }


    func pick_view(showFirst: Bool) {        
        //see above :)
    }


    func addSecondUIView(aView: UIView, dispStr : String) {

        let anotherView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y:60, width: 100, height: 50));

        anotherView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor();

        anotherView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;

        let someLabel : UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:5, y: 0, width: anotherView.frame.width, height:  anotherView.frame.height));

        someLabel.font  =   UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 23);
        someLabel.text  =   dispStr;
        someLabel.textColor     = UIColor.whiteColor();
        someLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;

        anotherView.addSubview(someLabel);

        aView.addSubview(anotherView);

        return;
    }


    func addSubviewButton(aView: UIView, return_msg: String, action_fcn : Selector) {

        let newButton : UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.RoundedRect);

        newButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true;                     //must be true for center to work

        newButton.setTitle(return_msg,      forState: UIControlState.Normal);
        newButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();

        //newButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 144, 30);                                  // or just use sizeToFit(), it's easier!
        newButton.sizeToFit();
        newButton.center = CGPointMake((UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width)/2, 250);     //must call after it's sized or won't work!

        //actions
        newButton.addTarget(self, action: action_fcn, forControlEvents:  .TouchUpInside);

        //add!
        aView.addSubview(newButton);

        return;
    }


    func press_launch(sender: UIButton!) {

        print("\(sender.titleLabel!.text!) was pressed and press_launch called");

        pick_view(false);

        return;
    }


    func press_return(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("\(sender.titleLabel!.text!) was pressed and press_return called");

        pick_view(true);

        return;
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() { super.didReceiveMemoryWarning(); }
}
```

Comment: And what is your issue exactly? What have you tried to achieve different slide directions? There is only one "issue" in your code - animation options (i.e. `TransitionCurlUp` or `TransitionFlipFromLeft`) are used only when using [`transitionWithView:...` or `transitionFromView:...`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:) methods.

Comment: I changed from 'UIView.animateWithDuration'() to  'UIView.transitionWithView()', but it still is not modifiable! The code does a different animation now, an expansive grow from offscreen-right for the new view. Also to note I have tried diff animations - uncomment out 'animationType' and try that :)!

Comment: And for the issue, as you ask, see "Observed Code Response -> [Problem]"... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Thank you Zach B!!!!

Here are the key changes made to the originating code for solution

- (*Transition Type*)  UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve was used for 'options:'
- (*Transition Direction*) Set by the initial offscreen location of view! See *xRemoved* in **pick_view()** for a clear example

And that's it!!!

For clarity and cleanliness of future inspection here is the **final working solution:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var viewOne : UIView!;
    var viewTwo : UIView!;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();

    gen_views();
    pick_view(true);

    return;
}

func gen_views() {

    viewOne = UIView();
    viewOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
    viewOne.frame = self.view.frame;

    addSecondUIView(viewOne, dispStr: "4:30 PM");
    addSubviewButton(viewOne, return_msg: "Launch View #1", action_fcn:  "press_launch:");

    viewTwo = UIView();
    viewTwo.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();
    viewTwo.frame = self.view.frame;

    addSecondUIView(viewTwo, dispStr: "8:00 PM");
    addSubviewButton(viewTwo, return_msg: "Return from View #2", action_fcn:  "press_return:");

    viewOne.frame = self.view.frame;
    viewTwo.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height);       //init off-screen

    self.view.addSubview(viewOne);                                    //add em both!
        self.view.addSubview(viewTwo);

        return;
}

    /**********************************************************************************************************************/
    /* @url    http://www.raywenderlich.com/86521/how-to-make-a-view-controller-transition-animation-like-in-the-ping-app */
    /**********************************************************************************************************************/
    func pick_view(showFirst: Bool) {

        let addedView   = (showFirst) ? viewOne : viewTwo;
        let removedView = (showFirst) ? viewTwo : viewOne;

        let xRemoved    = (showFirst) ? self.view.frame.width : -self.view.frame.width; // sets which dir it slides into view from

        addedView.alpha = 0;

        self.view.addSubview(addedView);

        print("old view off!");

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {

            print("new view added");

            addedView.alpha = 1.0;

            addedView.frame = self.view.frame;

            }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in

                print("old view removed");

                removedView.frame = CGRectMake(xRemoved, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height);

                removedView.removeFromSuperview();
        })

        return;
    }


func addSecondUIView(aView: UIView, dispStr : String) {        
    //see above post!
}


func addSubviewButton(aView: UIView, return_msg: String, action_fcn : Selector) {
    //see above post!
}


func press_launch(sender: UIButton!) {
    //see above post!
}


func press_return(sender: UIButton!) {
    //see above post!
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() { super.didReceiveMemoryWarning(); }
```

}

Comment: You shouldn't post parts of question as answers, as it most certainly is *not* an answer.

Comment: Losiowaty, what's your recommendation then :)? I thought it was ugly and obsfucated meaning by posting ALL of that 'junk' in the core question. The current post method is cleaner in my opinion! :)